# Create trigger with a cursor inside for multiple inserts

Tags: oracle, plsql, sqlplus

I want to create a trigger on every insert to the USERS table that will insert several entries to the BALANCES table, one entry for every coin id that exists in the SQL_COINS_VIEW view (hope i'm clear enough). The idea is that every time an account is created, it gets a balance 0 for each available coin in the list.

I tried this -

```
CREATE or REPLACE TRIGGER update_balances
AFTER INSERT
ON USERS
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
v_userid number(8);
cursor coinlist_cur is
select ID from SQL_COINS_VIEW;
BEGIN
select ID into v_userid from USERS;
For coinid in coinlist_cur
loop
insert into balances
(BALANCES_ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL,v_userid,coinid,0);
end loop;
END;
```

But i get an error -

```
Error(10,1): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
Error(11,42): PL/SQL: ORA-01747: invalid user.table.column, table.column, or column specification
```

The tables are structures this way -

```
SQL> desc SQL_COINS_VIEW;
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 ID                                        NOT NULL NUMBER(10)
 NAME                                      NOT NULL VARCHAR2(50)
 VALUE                                     NOT NULL NUMBER(18,6)
 UPDATETIME                                         NVARCHAR2(10)

SQL>
SQL> desc USERS;
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 ID                                        NOT NULL NUMBER(8)
 LOGINNAME                                 NOT NULL VARCHAR2(12)
 PASSWORD                                  NOT NULL VARCHAR2(12)
 EMAIL                                     NOT NULL VARCHAR2(50)
 PHONENUMBER                                        VARCHAR2(25)

SQL>
SQL> desc BALANCES;
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 ID                                        NOT NULL NUMBER(12)
 USERID                                    NOT NULL NUMBER(8)
 COINID                                    NOT NULL NUMBER(10)
 AMOUNT                                    NOT NULL NUMBER(30)
```

How can i properly create this trigger?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Your `insert` is missing the `values` keyword; the error is from it trying to interpret the values as column names. And `coinid` is a record, so you need to refer to a field within that, which is `id` in the cursor declaration:

```
insert into balances
values (BALANCES_ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL,v_userid,coinid.id,0);
```

It's good practice to list the columns too though.